# How to launch SPCK editor in termux using am command

Tags: android, termux, code-editor

I have made a bash file which makes a *code* command similar to that of VS code's code command.

I want to launch the SPCK editor to the specific project folder I want instead of opening the app from start. I want to know the activity class name or something like that for it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try inputting `cd storage/shared/android/data/io.spck/files` in your termux terminal or if you had installed the spck editor in another space disk use the `termux-setup-storage` to select the storage and run the first command. Then to select your project's name `cd projectName`. You can now call your preferred command to install packages into the selected project file, you can input `ls` to see the whole spck files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).